# Using MySQL in a Docker Container

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am kinda new to Docker and I am trying to build an image for a Django App using MySQL. The problem that I am having is, after running my image I get the following error : **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)")** . As a base for the image I am using `FROM django:python2` , I have installed the server using the following commands:

- `RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password X" | debconf-set-selections`
- `RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password X" | debconf-set-selections`
- `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server`

To fix the problem I tried multiple solutions, which I found on the internet such as:

- `RUN touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- `RUN chmod -R 755 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- `EXPOSE 3306`

Sadly, nothing worked. I also made sure the server is running, yet the problem is still there.

Comment: Let's see your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files. The database settings in `settings.py` could also help provide some insight.

Comment: As I am kinda new to stackoverflow as well I am not sure how to post a whole file. Honestly,I have written most of  the `Dockerfile` in the post except the `apt-get` for different modules etc. As for the `docker-compose` I wrote something briefly and it failed with the same error, so I decided to first get my `Dockerfile` running.

Comment: Are you able to get into the running container? `docker exec -it [your container name here] /bin/bash` will give you a shell where you can do some debugging. From inside the container you can try to see if mysql is even running (it doens't look like it is): `/etc/init.d/mysql status`

Comment: MySQL should be running as I have `RUN service mysql start`

Comment: What have you set `HOST` to in your database config ?

Comment: I first left it empty - didn't work, changed it to `localhost` - didn't work, changed it to `127.0.0.1` - didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example config that works really well.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Make sure to change the path to your `requirements.txt` file (if exists.)

*docker-compose.yml*

```
db:
  image: mysql
web:
  build: .
  environment:
    - PYTHONPATH=/code/server/
    - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=path.to.your.settings.file
  command: python server/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

Make sure to replace the path to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with the correct dotted-path to your settings file.

`docker-compose build`
then
`docker-compose up`

**EDIT**

If you use this config, change the value of `HOST` to `db` in your settings.py

Comment: I get the same error again but instead of (111) at the end its a (2) : **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")**

Comment: I have a quick question. Why did you write
 `environment:
    - PYTHONPATH=/code/server/`
And afterwards followed by `command: python server/manage.py` If i leave server before manage.py I get an error that it does not exist.